# Can't dereference a char* array passed through a function

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, void-pointers

The code is the following. The reason I'm using `void * args` is because this function has to be used in a threaded program. It was tested with and without any threads, and it doesn't work in any of both workflows. I'm pretty new to C and this might be obvious to the average programmer but even with gdb I can't find the problem.

```
void arg(const void* args) {
    char* arr = (char*) args;
    printf("%s", arr[0]);
    printf("%s", arr[1]);
    return;
}

int main (void) {
    char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};
    arg((void*)a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will segfault when dereferencing `args`.

Comment: `a` is an array of `char*`'s and it decays to `char**`. Enable warnings. See [demo with warnings](https://onlinegdb.com/wgSNO5rLN)

Comment: please tag only the language you are using. C != C++. I dont know C, but in C++ there is no need to use `void*` for threading via `std::thread`

Comment: Elements of a `char` array are single characters, not strings.

Comment: Do you really want C++ advice regarding this code?  If you are writing C, the answer should be "No".

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string`.  The `std::string` maintains it's length and is easier to pass to functions.

Comment: Since you tagged as C, remember to use the `str*()` functions with the C-String, character array.  For example, use `strcmp` instead of comparing the pointers.  Also, remember to allocate an extra slot in the array for the terminating nul character.

Comment: `a` in `main()` is an array of `char *`.   Passing the name of an array to a function converts it to a pointer to its first element which would be of type `char **`.   The type of `arr` in `arg()` therefore needs to be `char **`, not `char *`.

Comment: "The reason I'm using `void*`" - except you're not; you're using `const void *`.  Further, your types are strewn all over the place and you're "fixing" those by hard-casts. Casts aren't magic, and abusing them can, and will, hide root problems until runtime, leaving you scratching you head. That code should look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Eoex3nbGW).

Comment: `char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};` is **not valid C++**.

Comment: I think we should stop commenting on this until the OP clarifies which language he's using.

Comment: @PaulSanders True, I did not notice I added the C++ tag, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` have the type `char` after the casting

```
char* arr = (char*) args;
```

So at least using the conversion specifier `s` with objects of the type `char`

```
printf("%s", arr[0]);
printf("%s", arr[1]);
```

is incorrect.

It seems you mean the following

```
void arg(const void* args) {
    const char** arr = args;
    printf("%s", arr[0]);
    printf("%s", arr[1]);
}
```

Pay attention to that the array `a`

```
char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};
```

used in expressions (with rare exceptions) is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `char **`.

In C++ the array of string literals shall be declared with the qualifier `const`

```
const char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};
```

And you need explicitly casting the pointer of the type `const` void to the type `const char **` like for example

```
const char*const* arr = static_cast<const char * const *>( args );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was indeed thinking of char**. That makes more sense thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, `char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};` is not valid C++. If you enable warnings you'll see that we need to declare `a` as

```
vvvvv----------------------------------->added const 
const char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"}; //VALID
```

Also there is no need to cast anything to `void*` here. You can directly declare the parameter to be of type `const char**` as shown below:

```
void arg(const char** args) {
    
    std::cout<<args[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<args[1]<<std::endl;
    return;
}

int main () {
    const char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};
    arg(a);
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/fXNNlyOkaM)

Another option is to use `std::string` instead of string literals here.

---

> The reason I'm using `void * args` is because this function has to be used in a threaded program

```
void arg(const void* args) {
    const char*const* ptr = static_cast<const char * const *>( args );
    std::cout<<ptr[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<ptr[1]<<std::endl;
    return;
}

int main () {
//--vvvvv------------------------------------>added const
    const char* a[2] = {"Hello", "World!"};
//------v------------------------------------>no need to use cast here
    arg(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And the C version can look like:

```
void arg(void* args)
{
    const char** arr = args;
    printf("%s", arr[0]);
    printf("%s", arr[1]);
}
```